# How can i resize already stored images in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I need to resize images stored in firebase, but these image are in differents folders like this:

```
-bucket  
  -user
    -images
```

i need to go to images of the certains users and i would like to apply this script to resize the images

```
const storage = await getStorage();
const bucketName = `$socialmediaAPG.appspot.com/userId/images/`;
const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);
const files = await bucket.getFiles();
for (const file of files[0]) {
  const isImage = file.name.toLowerCase().includes('jpg') || file.name.toLowerCase().includes('jpeg');
  const isThumb = file.name.toLowerCase().includes('thumbs');
  if (isImage && !isThumb) {
    console.info(`Copying ${file.name}`);
    const metadata = await file.getMetadata();
    await file.copy(file.name);
    await file.setMetadata(metadata[0]);
  }
}
```

i am getting this error:

> Copying userId/images/image1.jpg Error: No such object: socialmediaAPG.appspot.com/userId/images/image1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This seems wrong:

```
file.copy(file.name)
```

The argument you pass to `file.copy` is the **destination** file name, so you're trying to copy the file onto itself.

You probably want to add your custom `thumbs` suffix to the destination file name with something like

```
file.copy(file.name+"thumbs")
```

For the actual resizing, I recommend checking out other [questions on resizing images in Cloud Storage](https://www.google.com/search?q=resize+images+in+google+cloud+storage+bucket+site:stackoverflow.com).

Comment: My code that I publish is not suitable to compress the size of the images? Can you help me with it please, I've been trying to do it for many days please!

Comment: You're not compressing the image yet. The link in my answer shows many questions about compressing images, so I recommend reading those, and trying it yourself. If you've done that, edit your question to show what you tried on the actual resizing.

Comment: i wan to use imageMagick to reduce the size, or should i buy the extension to reduce? i read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63043201/resize-all-images-stored-in-firebase-storage

Comment: The extension won't resize existing files in the bucket as far as I know. Calling ImageMagick to do the resizing is possible, but you'll have to write code for that. Lots of good articles here: https://www.google.com/search?q=use+imagemagick+to+resize+existing+images+in+cloud+storage. But the code in your question doesn't call any of that, so there's not much more I can do than what I already answered on (my guess) why you're guessting that error,.